# I am trying to implement a counter using react but cant seem to be able to clear the intervals properly

Tags: reactjs

I am fairly new to react and started out with a basic project but I'm struggling with a counter application that I am trying to make wherein the auto increment and the auto decrement function perform simultaneously so the count is not functioning properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

intervalId is a variable that has been defined globally in the component. The button click handlers are as mentioned below.

```
const stopInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    intervalId = null;
  };
 const handleAutoDecrement = () => {
    stopInterval();
    if (!intervalId) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter((prev) => prev - 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };

  const handleAutoIncrement = () => {
    stopInterval();
    if (!intervalId) {
      intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
      }, 1000);
    }
  };
```

I tried clearing the intervals in a return call back prior to this but got the same result so I am completely clueless so as to do what now.

Comment: Can you put this into stackblitz to better debug your problem.

Comment: do you want me to share my project demo here?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-xveabf?file=App.jsx

Comment: Click auto-increment then auto-decrement or vice-versa you'll see the problem im facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing `intervalId` in local variable and after every re-render its value gets undefined. You will have to store the value in a state so that when counter value changes and it renders again it must persist the `intervalId` value.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './style.css';

function CounterComponent() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const [intervalId, setintervalId] = useState();

  const stopInterval = () => {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    setintervalId();
  };

  const handleDecrement = () => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev - 1);
  };

  const handleAutoDecrement = () => {
    stopInterval();
    // if (!intervalId) {
      setintervalId(setInterval(() => {
        setCounter((prev) => prev - 1);
      }, 1000));
      console.log('interca', intervalId);
    // }
  };

  const handleAutoIncrement = () => {
    stopInterval();
    // if (!intervalId) {
      setintervalId(setInterval(() => {
        setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
      }, 1000));
    // }
  };
  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCounter((prev) => prev + 1);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="counterClass">{counter}</div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handleDecrement} className="decrementButton">
        Decrement
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleAutoDecrement} className="autoDecrementButton">
        AutoDecrement
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleAutoIncrement} className="autoIncrementButton">
        AutoIncrement
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleIncrement} className="incrementButton">
        Increment
      </button>
      <button onClick={stopInterval} className="incrementButton">
        Stop
      </button>
    </>
  );
}

export default CounterComponent;
```

Comment: We need to double click to get the opposite operation done now is there any particular reason for it?

Comment: I'm able to do it with single click. Are you using the exact same code?

Comment: The reason behind double click is that you are checking if `(!intervalId)` is not null. And when we call stopInterval we are clearing the intervalId but since state is an async task, it will complete once the function is fully completed. So you wont get the updated value(null) within that function itself. You will get it in the next function call. So for that reason I've removed that null if check.